# Status of JSTL in Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jstl

It seems JSTL is no longer even mentioned in the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html), Oracle instead favouring the JSF libraries heavily over the older jstl core libraries. Does this indicate that it is now unmaintained and will be scrapped in future version of the platform?

edit: 
Apparently the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) for the JSF tags includes documentation for the core tags. I'm not sure whether that means they are considered to be of core function any more though, since they aren't even any examples in the tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where's the official JSP tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845032/wheres-the-official-jsp-tutorial)

Comment: @Bozho thanks, my google fu failed me in finding that question. The answer there is helpful as well. I do not think they are exact duplicates.

Comment: well not exact, because one is about JSP and the other about JSTL, but they are virtually the same.

Comment: @Bozho wouldn't mind if it was closed, but did manage to track down the JSTL docs (see question). Surprisingly hard to find. Anyway, if it's closed, should merge that into the other question.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the PDF, it's mentioned.

Comment: My bad, it's actually mentioned briefly at http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijtu.html Strangely, they refer to JSTL 1.1, while javaee 6 is supposed to use 1.2